# VSCode PHP Debug extension path translation, local to server

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

Debugging PHP with Visual Studio Code and XDebug on the server. The server-side config goes:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so

xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.remote_host=mybox
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug/xdebug-remote.log
xdebug.remote_autostart=1

xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir=/tmp/xdebug
```

The configuration in launch.json goes:

```
    {
        "name": "Listen for XDebug",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9000,
        "localSourceRoot": "Y:\\",
        "serverSourceRoot": "/home/seva/myproject",
        "stopOnEntry":true
    }
```

Now, when the config is like this, and I bring up a page from that project in the browser, the debugger stops on first PHP line, and from that point on, I can set breakpoints and proceed to them. However, if I set a breakpoint in the same file, set `stopOnEntry` to `false` and load it in the browser, the breakpoint is not hit. What am I missing here?

EDIT: very straightforward code, one line statements, no symlinks there, the path mapping is given to VS Code.

EDIT2: found a funny line in the log:

```
<- breakpoint_list -i 5
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" 
xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_list" 
transaction_id="5">
    <breakpoint type="line" 
        filename="file:///home/seva/y:/admin_main.php"
        lineno="5" state="enabled" hit_count="0" hit_value="0" id="274990011">
    </breakpoint>
    <breakpoint type="line"
        filename="file:///home/seva/y:/db.php"
        lineno="770" state="enabled" hit_count="0" hit_value="0" id="274990010">
    </breakpoint>
</response>
```

Note the filename on the breakpoint object: `file:///home/seva/y:/admin_main.php`. It's a weird mash-up of local path and server path. The file really sits at `/home/seva/myproject` on the server box, which is shared over SAMBA as `\\servername\myproject` and then mapped to my local drive Y:.

Looks like `localSourceRoot` and `serverSourceRoot` don't work the way I thought...

EDIT3: when I change `localSourceRoot` to `myproject`, the entry in the log still has `file:///home/seva/y:/admin_main.php`. I don't see where can Y:\ come from, except it is the folder I'm editing in VS Code. So there's some funny interplay going on between those settings and the current folder path.

EDIT4: I think the culprit is the function `convertClientPathToDebugger()` under https://github.com/felixfbecker/vscode-php-debug/blob/5bfc474d681d5500d7b31d27bccdbfc08b88884e/src/paths.ts . It looks right though - take the local relative path, apply to server root, get server path.

If only I could step through that...

Comment: What kind of lines those are? For multi-line statements .. the actual line is somewhere in the middle .. so it's good idea only set breakpoints on simple/single line statements. Don't know how VSC exactly works (PhpStorm user here) but maybe it's somehow related to path mappings? Just a reminder -- xdebug (or possibly PHP itself) will use final/resolved paths while IDE/editor should be using path as is. So if you have symbolic links or stuff like that on remote side .. better take that into an account. Will placing `xdebug_break();` in actual code break where needed with that option = `false`?

Comment: Would be good to see xdebug logs for "true" and "false" sessions where breakpoints are hit in both cases. Right now I would suggest creating new simple script with few simple lines in it, each instruction on new line, and see how it behaves there. Something like `<?php $a = 5; $b = 3; $c = $a + $b; echo $c;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in the PHP Debug extension, it treats Windows drive letters in a case sensitive manner. Changing the value of `localSourceRoot` to `y:\` helped.

https://github.com/felixfbecker/vscode-php-debug/issues/197
https://github.com/felixfbecker/vscode-php-debug/pull/198